# R pdf plot text overlap

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, cyrillic

I've read a ton of post and didn't find any good answer. I have overlapping text on labs. I'm trying:

```
pdf(file = "office.loaded6.pdf")
plot(seq,type="l",lwd=3,xlab="Time",ylab="Загруженность")
dev.off()
```

well, this is actual plot, but it's no different, I still can't have normal titles for axis.

[image: text overlaps]

Comment: What operating system do you use? I guess it's some encoding related rendering problem on windows, because it works fine on my linux machine.

Comment: What happens when you try to use Latin characters? Is the kerning still wrong? Try using a different typeface.

Comment: Maybe a workaround would be to output as `PNG`, then convert to `PDF`? Just tested output as `PNG`, output looks OK.

Comment: I use Win7. 
Png works good, that is handy idea to make png->pdf. Latin also works good. Thx for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I use `ISOLatin7` encoding. The graphics looks good  when I open it in `SumatraPDF`, but looked as ugly as yours when I opened it in `Adobe Acrobat Reader DC`.

I found the solution. It's not perfect but might serve your needs. You can write your `ylab` like this:

```
ylab = paste("З", "а", "г", "р", "у", "ж", "е", "н", "н", "о", "с", "т", ь")
```

It's a little annoying to write text like that, but still better move than save graphics as png.

P. s. this method won't work for overlaping graphics' titles and legends.

**Edited:**
More efficient way, which I found recently is to use `expression`. This command works for everything: axis names, titles and legend. For naming `y` axis you simply need to write:

```
 ylab = expression(Загруженность)
```

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.